# How do I render a modal with information from an item in the list when clicked on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am rendering a list from an API. When I click on an item on the list I want a detailed modal to be rendered with information related to the list item being clicked on. How would I go about this ?

The modal is being rendered from index.html with an ID of root. So that it can hover over other components.

Inside renderlist.js the list is being rendered, when i click on the Item.Header  of the particular item in the list the modal needs to show the a detailed info related to that item in the list.
//RenderList.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {getList, clearList} from '../../actions';
import { Button, Icon, Image, Item, Label, Rating, Modal, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import '../../styles.css';
import PopUp from '../popups/popup';
import ALModal from '../popups/ALModal';





class RenderList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        isOpen: false
        listId: "",
        listName: "",
      };

    };


  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: true,
    });
  }
    renderList() {
     return this.props.list.map(l => {
       return (
    <Item className="list" style={{ marginLeft:"3px", marginTop: "2px", borderRadius: "7px", borderWidth: "2px", borderColor: "#0F4376", borderStyle: "solid", width: "95%"}} >
      <Item.Content style={{padding: "10px"}}>
        <div style={{paddingTop: "10px", paddingLeft:"10px", width: "200px"}}><Rating className= "ui blue" style={{color: "#0F4376"}} defaultRating={l.rating} maxRating={5}  icon="star" size="huge"  disabled /></div>
        <div  style={{marginLeft: "16px", marginTop:"8px", width: "280px"}}>
          <Item.Header onClick={this.showModal} style={{borderStyle: "", color: "#0F4376", marginTop: "10px", fontSize:"18px", fontWeight: "900"}} as='a'>{l.provider_name}</Item.Header>
        </div>
        <Fragment>{this.state.isOpen == false ? null : <ALModal name={l.provider_name}/>}</Fragment>



        <div style={{ marginLeft:"50%", display: "inline-block", marginTop: "-25px" }}>
          <Item.Extra>
            <div >
              <Label className="label" basic style={{borderRadius: "70px", color: "#0F4376", borderColor:"#0F4376", padding:"10px 10px", fontSize: "13px", fontWeight: "1" }} icon='globe' content="Website" />
              <Label basic style={{borderRadius: "70px", color: "#0F4376", borderColor:"#0F4376", padding:"10px 10px", fontSize: "13px", fontWeight: "1"}} icon='calendar' content='Book Tour' />
              <Label basic style={{borderRadius: "70px", color: "#0F4376", borderColor:"#0F4376", padding:"10px 10px", fontSize: "13px", fontWeight: "1"}} icon='envelope' content='Message' />
            </div>
          </Item.Extra>

        </div>
        <p style={{ marginTop:"-20px",marginLeft: "16px",color: "#7495A9", fontSize: "16px", fontWeight: "900", borderStyle: "", width: "270px"}}>{l.city} , {l.state} - {l.phone_number}</p>
        <div style= {{marginTop: "-7px", marginLeft: "15px" ,width: "150px", borderStyle: ""}}><img src={require('../../resources/logo4.png')} className="ui small image" /></div>


      </Item.Content>
    </Item>
           );
           });
   }

    render() {
    return (
   <div style={{marginBottom: "200px"}}>
     <div style= {{}}>
       <Item.Group style={{ overflow: "auto", maxHeight: "50vh"}}  className="scroller">{this.renderList()}</Item.Group>
     </div>
     <div>

     </div>
   </div>

            );
         }

  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      list: Object.values(state.list)
    };
  };



export default connect(mapStateToProps, { clearList })(RenderList);
```

//SearchFacilities.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import history from '../../history';
import '../../styles.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getList, clearList} from '../../actions';
import { Responsive, Button, Form, Grid, Header, Message, Segment, Modal, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import qs from "qs";
import axios from 'axios';
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';
import { url } from "../utils/RestUtils";
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import RenderList from './RenderList';
import MapContainer from '../gmaps/mapapp';
import ALModal from '../popups/ALModal';





const options = [
  { key: 1, text: 'Assisted Living', value: 'Assisted Living Facility' },
  { key: 2, text: 'Skilled Nursing', value: 'Skilled Nursing' },
  { key: 3, text: 'Adult Day Care', value: 'Adult Day Care' },
  { key: 4, text: 'Palliative', value: 'Adult Day Care' },
  { key: 5, text: 'Provider', value: 'Provider' },
  { key: 6, text: 'Hospice', value: 'Hospice' },
  { key: 7, text: 'Hospital', value: 'Hospital' },
]

export class SearchFacilities extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      zipCode: "",
      options: "",
      listRen: false,
      test: "good",
      lat: "33.7490",
      lng: "-84.3880",
      clicked: true,
      isOpen: false

    };
  }



    onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("inside onSubmit");
    console.log(this.state);
    this.props.clearList();
     await this.props.getList(this.state.zipCode, this.state.options);
    console.log(this.props.list[0].lat);
    await this.setState({lat: this.props.list[0].lat, lng: this.props.list[0].lng})
    await this.setState({listRen: true, test: "bad"});

    console.log(this.state);


}


  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  onChangeDropdown = (event, data) => {
    this.setState({options: data.value})
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(this.props);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div style= {{marginTop: "-50px"}}>
        <div style = {{marginLeft: "50%", paddingTop:"2.5%"}}>{this.state.listRen == false ? <MapContainer  list={this.props.list}/> : <MapContainer list={this.props.list} ren={this.state.listRen} latt={this.state.lat} lngg={this.state.lng}/> }</div>
          <div className="" style={{marginRight: "50%", paddingTop: "0px"}}>
            <form style={{marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "50px", marginRight: "24=7%"}} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div style={{}}>
                <h1 style={{color: "#0F4376", fontSize:""}} >Search below to find facilities in your area.</h1>
                <div style={{marginTop: "20px"}} className="ui big icon input">


                  <Dropdown style={{width: "265px"}}
                    search
                    onChange={this.onChangeDropdown}
                    name="options"
                    selection
                    wrapSelection={false}
                    options={options}
                    placeholder='Assisted Living Facility'
                  />
                  <input style={{marginLeft: "10px", width:"200px"}} type="text" placeholder="57115" name="zipCode" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  <button style={{marginLeft: "10px", width: "150px", backgroundColor: "#0F4376", color:"white"}} className="ui button" >Search</button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </form>

          <div style={{marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "50px"}}>
            <hr style= {{marginRight: "33px"}}/>
          </div>

          <div style={{marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "50px", borderStyle: "soild"}}>
            <RenderList style={{}}></RenderList>
          </div>


        </div>

      </div>

          )
        }
          }


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    list: Object.values(state.list)
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getList, clearList })(SearchFacilities);
```

//ALModal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const ALModal = ({name}) => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div style = {{marginLeft: "52%", height:"50%", width: "32%", marginTop: "14%", display: "block",
      position: "fixed",
      zIndex: "1",
      overflow: "auto",
      backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)", boxShadow:"0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.01) "}} className="ui active modal">

      <div>

        <table width="450">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h1>{name}</h1>
              <p>this section contains  website, book tour, request info, etc. </p>
              <hr />
              <p>Address: 1245 street</p>
              <p>Phone: (404)555-3232
                <hr />
              </p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table width="450" align="left">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="420" align="center">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"><img src="https://cdn.aarp.net/content/dam/aarp/politics/advocacy/2019/03/1140-hospital-sign.jpg" height="185" />
</td>
<td>
<center>
<img src="https://technical.ly/philly/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/09/I0A4495-e1536787485218.jpg" height="80" />
</center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="https://amp.businessinsider.com/images/5810c57eb28a645d008b4fa8-750-563.jpg" height="90" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>,

    document.querySelector('#modal')
  );
};

export default ALModal;
```

//listreducer.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
  FETCH_LIST,
  CLEAR_LIST,
} from '../actions/types';

const DEFAULT = {};
const EMPTY = {};

export default (state = DEFAULT, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LIST:
       console.log("inside LISTREDUCER FETCH_LIST");
       console.log(action.payload);
       return {...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, "provider_name")};
       case CLEAR_LIST:
        return EMPTY;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//mapKeys is a function from lowdash that takes an array and returns an object.
```

if there were multiple items in the list. For example :
1) Fruits
2) Eggs
3) Chicken

when i click on an Item i want to the modal to be rendered with the information contained in the list.

Comment: This is way to much code for an SO question...

Comment: can you post some more code, I'm not getting the full picture from this little bit of code you posted

Comment: If you can, reduce your code or craete a codepen.

Comment: reduced it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made a basic implementation for what you are asking. You can easily modify this to work with your implementation.

Essentially I am creating a new modal for each of the header items. The trigger, or the component that opens the modal is defined within the modal component itself. Currently, everything is stateless and uncontrolled but could easily be modified to be the stateful and controlled.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-euclid-jek0m

I did not use your code as I don't want to have to debug everything that you gave. If you want a more specific answer using your code, please consider making a https://codesandbox.io with your code as it is and then I or someone can modify it to work.